# define EntityManageFactory and Transactional beans in separate contex

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, applicationcontext

I have a context by name `dao-context.xml` as following:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" lazy-init="true" destroy-method="close">
<!--   define data source properties  -->
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
     <!--   define another properties  -->
</beans>

<!-- define dao object and set jpaTemplate -->

<bean id="doa_obj" class="DaoObject">
    <!-- set jpa template -->
</bean>
```

and load this context as following:

```
public class DaoFactory
{
    private static ApplicationContext dao_ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("dao-context.xml");
    public static ApplicationContext getDaoCtx()
    {
        return dao_ctx;
    }
}
```

then I define `Biz Layer` context as following with name "biz_layer.xml":

```
<bean id="ctx" class="dao.DaoFactory" factory-method="getDaoCtx"/>

<bean factory-bean="ctx" factory-method="getBean" id="emf">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="biz_obj" class="BizObject" />
```

and `BizObject` define as following:

```
@Transactional
public class BizObject
{
     @Transactional
     public void issueDoc()
     {
         ((DaoObject)DaoFactory.getDaoCtx().getBean("Dao_Obj")).save(new DaoEntity('Arture'));
     }
}
```

and in end I have a main method as following:

```
Public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         ApplicationContext biz_ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("biz_layer.xml");
         BizObject bizObj = (BizObject)biz_ctx.getBean("biz_obj");
         bizObj.issueDoc();
    }
}
```

---

I with test by several scenarios.

- When I run `Main` class any exception not raise but any record not committed on `data base`.
- When I debug `Main` class, `bizObj` variable is not a proxy.
- When I define `biz_obj` bean to `dao_context.xml` and in `Main` class initialize it ,  `bizObj` is  proxy and `@Transactional` worked fine and committed into `data base`.
- When I programmatically manage `Transaction` all thing worked fine.

---

My question is:

What when define all of bean contain `Dao` layer bean and `Biz` layer beans in same context all thing worked fine but when separate then in separate context `@Transactional` annotation not worked and any exception not raise so.

Comment: It will not work this way also you shouldn't load the context yourself. You should have a single context loading all xml files. Also imho this explicit layering is a bad thing, especially with large applications.

Comment: please explain your reason for this layering bad idea.

Comment: You shouldn't do an explicit technical layering, things that belong together should be put together. 25 services in a service package don't belong together. Now you make it even worse by making each layer an explicit application context, especially when using AOP (transactions) this can be painful. With transactions you could have 2 different instances of your transaction mechanism interfering with each other.